# Can Scala Array add new element

Tags: scala

When I created a Scala Array and added one element, but the array length is still 0, and I can not got the added element although I can see it in the construction function.

```
scala> val arr = Array[String]()
arr: Array[String] = Array()

scala> arr:+"adf"
res9: Array[String] = Array(adf)

scala> println(arr(0))
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
  ... 33 elided
```

Comment: You're creating a new array with `:+` which is stored in `res9` in your example since you didn't assign it to anywhere else. You can find the new element in that array. The original array is not altered in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared Array of 0 size. It cannot have any elements. Your array is of size 0. `Array[String]()` is a array contructor syntax.

`:+` creates a new Array with with the given element so the old array is empty even after doing the `:+` operation.

You have to use `ofDim` function to declare the array first of certain size and then you can put elements inside using `arr(index) = value` syntax.

Once declared array size do not increase dynamically like list. Trying to append values would create new array instance.

or you can initialize the array during creation itself using the `Array("apple", "ball")` syntax.

```
val size = 1
val arr = Array.ofDim[String](size)
arr(0) = "apple"
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val size = 1
size: Int = 1

scala> val arr = Array.ofDim[String](size)
arr: Array[String] = Array(null)

scala> arr(0) = "apple"

scala> arr(0)
res12: String = apple
```

Comment: @tkachuko array size do not increase dynamically

Comment: @tkachuko trying to append would create new Array instances and Arrays are mutable